# Use and effects of Javascript Conditional Redirect based on GeoIP

Tags: javascript

I am thinking of adding a country-specific javascript conditional redirect code right beneath the opening  'head' tags of all the pages in my website. This is intended to redirect visitors from certain countries to a different version of the site. What I am worried about is whether this will cause any problem with the Search Engines or affect my SEO/SERP, e.g. preventing the SE from crawling and/or indexing the current page, etc ?

Secondly, I am not fully sure whether this redirect will really work. Here is the code --

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country == "2_letter_country_code_here") 
{
  window.location = "http://www.Target_URL_for_Redirection.com";
} else {
  window.location = "http://www.URL_of_the_Current_Page.com";
}
</script>

bla..bla...
...
...
</head>
```

Source: [here][1] [1]: http://www.geekhelpguide.com/javascript/easy-country-based-redirect-in-javascript/

1. The first line probably pulls data from the Maxmind (maxmind.com) GeoIP database. How reliable is this? Are these databases continuously updated, since I understand IP range of a country is dynamic and changes all the time?
2. My main and only goal here is to redirect the visitors from certain country/countries (visitors from '2_letter_country_code' above) to another URL, BUT *everybody else* MUST be able to continue with the CURRENT page without being redirected anywhere else or experiencing any other problem because of this. What do you think?
3. Will this cause any problems for the Search Engines in any way, or affect the SEO/SERP performance of the 'Current Page' ? If so, what can be done to correct that?

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

First of all IP ranges are not per country. Companies/Persons buys IP ranges or rents an IP or range from a company owning a  range.

What Maxmind tries to achieve is to maps a single IP or range to a geo location.

**How they could do this?**

- Well you can do a `whois` query for an ip which returns the holder with address, but this would be the most inaccurate mapping, because you don't know where the IP is finally used (One business travel i use the companies VPN so i always have the same IP, to you would not know where i am).
- ISP often use a certain IP range for a certain region only. To get this information they either need collaborate with these ISP or with sites that do speed test where users can enter their zip and city.

**How accurate is this data?**
For ISP for home users it is ok. At least you have a raw guess, and you have a high probability that you know form which country the users is visiting your page (If the user is not using a proxy or vpn).
The *accuracy* for region of the country depends on the ISPs, because there is no rule that they have to use certain IP ranges for certain regions.
E.g. whit mobile devices there are some ISPs that use their whole mobile IP range for the whole country.

Honestly i don't know what the IP for mobile devices is with roaming. If it is the local IP or the one of my Mobile network operator.

With this being said, you can assume that the match for countries is relatively high, if you target *normal* internet users. With company networks which have their own IPs you could/would have more wrong mappings.

**2.**

If you don't want to block users out but redirect them a country based entry page this approach should be ok for you. But always keep in mind that you could o a false assumption. E.g. when i'm traveling and i open well known page where i want to visit the page related to my home country and not the one where i'm currently at, then it would be ok for me if i'm redirected, but i should have the possibility to switch to the correct page.
Thats the same problem as with language. It is ok to guess what the user wants to see, but always make sure that it is easy for the user to correct your assumption.

**3.**

That depends on how yo do it. Search Engines visit you page without javascript (there are some exception), but generally they follow only plain `window.location = ...`. To be sure you should e.g. use googles Webmastertools to see how google bot sees the given page.
If you do redirect (no matter if this is by header or by javascript) then do it always in a way that it does no show additional content to the search engine that is never visible for the visitor.
But as this depends how you implement the redirect it is not possible to tell if it has a bad impact on SEO. I can just say it is possible to do in a way that you don't have bad impact.

Comment: No, I am not targeting only <i>normal</i> individual/private internet users. My target is any potential buyers - both individual and company.

Comment: So what's the bottom line? I don't really mind if someone from the target country (for redirection) is not re-directed and lands on the 'current' page despite the code. But if any unintended person (i.e. not from the target country for redirection) is redirected, that would be really disappointing, because that might mean I may lose that visitor. Is there any chance of that happening with this code?

Comment: ...I am not sure what you mean by 'how you implement the redirect'. I want to implement it exactly the way I quoted the code above - right beneath the opening head-tag. Everything else comes after that. That's all. What do you think?

Comment: By the way, how do you block instead of 'redirect'? Is that more effective?  What do you think of this method of blocking: http://azuliadesigns.com/block-website-access-country/  ? Will it work?

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for your 1st answer and for the coming ones. It's been a great help. :)